# Missing region parameter in AWS S3?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-s3

I am implementing Amazon Web Services in my `Symofony 3.4` project but when I trigger my testing url it throws:

```
Missing required client configuration options:
  region: (string)  A region configuration value is required.
```

My region is console is EU(Ireland) and I have checked documentation and put parameter by that.

This is my `service.yml`

```
 demo_storage:
    class: App\Service\S3\S3Service
    arguments:
        - "test.app" # Name of Bucket
        - credentials:
            key:     "%amazon_key%"
            secret:  "%amazon_secret%"
            region:  "eu-west-1"    
            version: "2006-03-01"      
    public: true
```

Comment: so you decided to roll your own class? (just assuming from the classname). I believe region and version are *not* part of the credentials. in the AwsClient class of the sdk region/version are on the same level as credentials, not as the aws-key. when you roll your own class, you might want to also provide the source code ......

Comment: Thank you for replay. It's was problem in syntax within yml file for Symony 3* version. @Jakumi